# Not receiving "Retry After" headers from MS Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm not receiving the `Retry After` header from the MS Graph API when I get throttled (ie. 429 errors). I also created an [issue on github](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript/issues/42) repo for the javascript client library, but this probably isn't an issue with the library. Not sure how to debug this...

Comment: Can you be more explicit in this question?  I'm guessing from the GitHub issue that this looks like an error coming from a request to the Excel APIs (on OneDrive)?  Can you provide an example error response here too please?

Comment: The spreadsheet is in a Sharepoint library. Here's an example 429 response missing the `Retry After` header.

Comment: `{ 'cache-control': 'private',
  'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'request-id': '27f60550-c048-4426-9280-985f794e0bbc',
  'client-request-id': '27f60550-c048-4426-9280-985f794e0bbc',
  'x-ms-ags-diagnostic': '{"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"West US","Slice":"SliceA","ScaleUnit":"002","Host":"AGSFE_IN_1","ADSiteName":"WST"}}',
  duration: '110.9207',
  date: 'Fri, 03 Nov 2017 22:34:10 GMT',
  connection: 'close' },`

Answer (score 1):

The Excel REST API is [implemented by SharePoint](https://blogs.office.com/en-us/2009/11/09/excel-services-in-sharepoint-2010-rest-api-examples/?eu=true) in the case of a SharePoint hosted file.
The SharePoint REST API sends [503's and not 429's when throttling and doesn't support the retry-after header](http://www.wictorwilen.se/sharepoint-2013-sharepoint-health-score-and-throttling-deep-dive).
Only [OneDrive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/errors) and [Exchange API's](https://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2017/04/throttling-coming-to-outlook-apis/) support retry after as far as I know. (Having an issue with Exchange ATM though)
([AAD](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2017/04/07/throttling-coming-to-outlook-api-and-microsoft-graph/) also seems to have implemented the limitations, but it's not clear if it implements retry-after or not)
I added a [uservoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/32797489-consistent-retry-after-information-accross-differe) comment about that, upvote it to help :) (still under validation, might take a couple of hours to appear)

Comment: I found something similar with the Excel APIs. I'm using the spreadsheets to update several namedRanges in a spreadsheet and then read back several  namedRanges. The errors weren't correlating with the amount of calls I was making - we were still in development and the volume was very low... Like your situation, it had to do with limitations of the service itself. In my case, the errors essentially disappeared after refactoring the code to wait until after all the updates were done before trying to read back any data. A bug in the initial version would sometimes send requests out of order...

Answer (score 0):

I found that when querying SharePoint lists and libraries through the Graph API, if you hit SharePoint throttling limits then the Graph does return 429 with no retry info in the headers. That's the short answer, here's a much longer post I wrote about this https://camerondwyer.wordpress.com/2018/01/31/microsoft-graph-api-throttling-sharepoint-lists-libraries-http-429-error-code/